# How can i raise an event based on distance

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, geolocation

I need to send Geolocation to server in 2 scenarios.
1. particular time interval,say 300000 ms(configurable)
and
2. whenever device moves a particular distance,say 500 mtrs(configurable)
First scenario has done using setInterval() in javascript.
How can i raise an event based on distance.
I am using jquery Mobile with phonegap/cordova.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this other than checking the difference of geolocation in particualar interval of time

Comment: Yes there is. With Artificial Intelligence using the the fuzzy set theory you can calculate the distance between 2 points  -- http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5137

Comment: You could do something like [this](http://pastebin.com/GfMqFPXA).